# Oracle+Spring Security Authentication: SQLException: Invalid column index

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, spring-security

I'm using Spring MVC+Security and Oracle 10g. When I try authenticate I get the following error:

```
Error : PreparedStatementCallback; invalid ResultSet access for SQL [SELECT PAYGATEMANAGER.AUTHENTICATION_PKG.getUser(?) FROM DUAL]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
```

security.xml:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query=
                "SELECT PAYGATEMANAGER.AUTHENTICATION_PKG.getUser(?) FROM DUAL"
            authorities-by-username-query=
                "SELECT PAYGATEMANAGER.AUTHENTICATION_PKG.getAuthorities(?) FROM DUAL" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

PL/SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PAYGATEMANAGER.AUTHENTICATION_PKG AS
TYPE T_REFCURSOR IS REF CURSOR;

  FUNCTION getUser(username IN VARCHAR2) RETURN T_REFCURSOR;  
  FUNCTION getAuthorities(username IN VARCHAR2) RETURN T_REFCURSOR;

END AUTHENTICATION_PKG;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PAYGATEMANAGER.AUTHENTICATION_PKG AS 

FUNCTION getUser(username IN VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN T_REFCURSOR IS
        userInfo T_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

    OPEN userInfo FOR
    SELECT
        U.NAME AS username ,
        P.PASSWORD AS password,
        'true' AS enabled            
    FROM
        PAYGATEMANAGER.USERS U INNER JOIN PAYGATEMANAGER.PASSWORDS P
        USING(USER_ID)
    WHERE 
        U.NAME = username;

RETURN userInfo;
END;

FUNCTION getAuthorities(username IN VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN T_REFCURSOR IS
        userAuthorities T_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

    OPEN userAuthorities FOR
    SELECT
        U.NAME AS username ,
        UR.ROLE AS authorities           
    FROM
        PAYGATEMANAGER.USERS U INNER JOIN PAYGATEMANAGER.USERS_ROLES UR
        USING(USER_ID)
    WHERE 
        U.NAME = username;

RETURN userAuthorities;
END;

END AUTHENTICATION_PKG;
```

I think the reason is in return type T_REFCURSOR, which is not fetching into username, password, enabled. But how to fix this? To add some functionality in future (e.g. login attempts audit) I think I should do it in PL/SQL functions, not hard coding in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely won't work with the "out of the box" [JdbcDaoImpl](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.html) (which is what `<jdbc-user-service>` maps to). I would suggest reviewing the source code of the standard implementation, and then writing your own implementation which implements the Spring Security `UserDetailsService`, but uses JDBC and `CallableStatement` under the covers.

You will declare your implementation class as a regular spring bean:

```
 <bean id="MyPlsqlUserDetailsService" class="my.great.JdbcCallableStatementImpl"/>
```

... and then use the `ref` attribute on `<user-details-service>` as follows:

```
 <user-details-service ref="MyPlsqlUserDetailsService"/>
```

(Note that I'm omitting the intricacy of XML namespaces etc etc, hopefully you understand those).

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I understand. Thank you for help, I'll try to implement your advice.

Comment: I've read some chapters from your book. The most complete book in Spring Security I think, it helped me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! Let me know if you would like any other advice on this question.